# Why is Pentaho Report Designer adding parameter named "ce" to Database Connection of the report?

Tags: java, pentaho, mssql-jdbc, pentaho-report-designer

I am forced to use Pentaho Report Designer 5.4 and have following problem: Every time i try to make changes to Database Connection of the report, inside Options section designer adds parameter "ce" without any value - even if i previously deleted it (please see images below). When i open .prpt file and look inside sql-ds.xml, connection url looks as follows: `"jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.194:1433;databaseName=statdb;integratedSecurity=false;ce"`

problem is that  my report was not loading at all. I looked into report log and found following lines:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Util.parseUrl(Util.java:445) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.parseAndMergeProperties(SQLServerDriver.java:1026) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1008) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:na]
```

I assume that appending parameter "ce" is causing the problem. 
I have 2 questions:

1. Why is Pentaho Report Designer adding parameter named "ce" to Database Connection of the report?
2. Is Connection url in right format? Is parameter "ce" appended correctly?

   [image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 'instance name' defined such fashion. In your case option is blank since as I see on UI Instance name is also blank.

This is a bug most probably - 'ce' automatically added when connection edited. If you don't want database editor attempts to tweak you connection string such fashion - use 'Generic database' connection. You will have to specify full java class name and connection jdbc connection string. Also you have to have this jdbc driver on classpath and it can workaround most of such 'edit connection' issues.

Full guide can be found [jdbc sqlserver dirver class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526(v=sql.110).aspx)

[image]

Comment: Dear @Dzmitry Prakapenka Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that my report was not loading at all. I edited my answer.

My Guess is that appending parameter "ce" was causing the problem - the report was not loading at all. Do you agree? Unfortunately i can not test this.

Comment: If report is not loading most probably there is exception stack-trace. It is hard to guess why it is not loading otherwise. There is cases when report definition cannot be loaded - but if you have screenshot - it is actually loaded. When report cannot be generated (after the report definition loaded) - in this case pop-up with stack-trace is shown in report designer or same stack-trace in server logs or whatever - stack-traces extremely useful to determine what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Run this query and get your **instance name**, and assign that value to the **ce** property in the **Options tab** and there you go :)

```
SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName, SUSER_NAME() LoggedInUser,SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [ServerName],
                     SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS [ServerInstanceName],
            SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS [Instance],
            SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS [Edition],
            SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS [ProductVersion],
                     Left(@@Version, Charindex('-', @@version) - 2) As VersionName
```